# sparse matrix from dictionaries

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I just started to learn to program in Python and I am trying to construct a sparse matrix using Scipy package.  I found that there are different types of sparse matrices, but all of them require to store using three vectors like  row, col, data; or if you want to each new entry separately, like S(i,j) = s_ij you need to initiate the matrix with a given size.
My question is if there is a way to store the matrix entrywise without needing the initial size, like a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use usual dictionary with tuples of two integers as indices. For example:

```
matrix = {}
matrix[5, 7] = 1
matrix[3, 8] = 5
```

Comment: you don't need parenthesis around the tuple

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did initially save the entries as a dictionary, but eventually I need the sparse structure to perform computations, and that's what I was trying to do earlier in one step.  
I did find that there's no way around this.

Comment: As JBernardo pointed out `matrix[5, 7] = 1` is more concise, but not as explicit

Comment: @Diego Matrix multiplication, addition, sqrt, etc works fine on the sparse dicts of sparse dicts--they behave just like 2-D lists of lists, or numpy sparse matrices--they index like `matrix[5][7] = 1`. A 4-liner should be all you need for any matrix/vector operation. just assume zero (or whatever you need) for gaps in the data. A `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s would be a drop-in replacement for any operation on lists of lists, but it would also probably use more memory than a fully-populated list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

No. Any matrix in Scipy, sparse or not, must be instantiated with a size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I finally realised that I need to store the matrix in two steps, one for reading all the data and another to store, in whichever method I want.  But now I'm happy with this procedure.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that works fine. Perhaps you can use `max` to quickly find the maximum indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic={}
a,b=int(input("Enter the order:")),int(input())
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        c=int(input())
        if c!=0:
            dic[(i,j)]=c
if len(dic)<=(a+b)/2:
    print("sparse metrix")
else:
    print("non sparse metrix")

for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        print(dic.get((i,j),0),end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Please explain the answer rather than just posting a solution "we are not a code writing service" this way it will be beneficial to others in the future as well